# Run tox and docker-compose in .gitlab-ci.yml failed connection to localhost

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I would like to set up Tox and docker-compose inside GitLab, and when Tox run it will execute test cases that access to PostgreSQL. I am very new to GitLab and Docker concept so the way I try to approach might not be properly set up.

When GitLab Pipline is run, docker-compose seems to process without problem (database is created and some data can be inserted via 'box-test-migrations' container. However when Tox is executed, it generates errors.

I have defined .git-ci.yml like this:

```
image: docker/compose:latest

services:
  - docker:stable-dind

before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache py-pip
  - apk add --no-cache gcc libffi-dev openssl-dev libc-dev python3-dev
  - python --version
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - docker version
  - docker-compose --version

stages:
  - Test

tox-ci:
  stage: Test
  script:
  - pip install tox
  - docker-compose -f config/docker/docker-compose.ci.yml down
  - docker-compose -f config/docker/docker-compose.ci.yml up -d --build
  - cat /etc/hosts
  - sleep 10
  - docker-compose -f config/docker/docker-compose.ci.yml logs --tail="all"
  - tox -e ci
coverage: '/^TOTAL.*\s+(\d+\%)$/'
```

I have docker-compose.ci.yml like this

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  bbbox-test-database:
    container_name: bbbox-test-database
    image: debezium/postgres
    env_file:
      - ../env/ci.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=bbbox-test-database
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d bbbox_test -U db_user"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - default

  bbbox-test-migrations:
    image: bbbox-test-migrations
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: config/docker/migrations.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ../env/ci.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=bbbox-test-database
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    links:
      - bbbox-test-database
    depends_on:
      - bbbox-test-database
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
```

In ci.env file I have database related variables like this:

```
POSTGRES_USER=db_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
POSTGRES_DB=bbbox_test
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

Here is error messages I got:

```
------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------
612 WARNING  root:database.py:39 Try to connect: 1 times
613 WARNING  root:database.py:40 Connecting to DB: localhost:bbbox_test
614 WARNING  root:database.py:52 Error connecting to database: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5432), [Errno 99] Address not available :Re-try in 5 sec.
```

I tried to add below data in .gitlab-ci.yml but it then generates error docker is not running message:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
```

Any advise would be really appreciated

Comment: Hmm yes localhost would not work because the context of the gitlab runner is not the "host" but another docker container so even if you expose the port it would not work with "localhost". I'm not sure which network is used for the gitlab runners, but maybe it's also "default", so have you already tried `bbbox-test-database` as `POSTGRES_HOST` for Tox?

Comment: Yes I tried and that didn't work. Some comment I found said "Docker inside docker communicate via localhost" To my understanding Tox is running in outer docker and that can't communicate to inner docker which run database. It is missing something, I just don't know what.

Comment: thank you for that example file. It helped me out a lot.